# Executing python scripts-windows

Tags: python, windows, cmd

How can i execute a python script before a pyqt4 gui is started? Basically, when the user launches the application, a CMD console startsup and runs the python script, how do I do that?

Comment: Can you describe a little more of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: When someone launches my GUI application on Windows, I want a CMD console to pop up and run a few python scripts before the actual GUI pops up/starts.

Comment: Why not just run those python scripts inside your app before you pop up the window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a batch file wrapper:

```
Run_program.bat:

python script1.py
python script2.py
run_program.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Make *.py scripts opened with python by default. On Linux it can be achieved by adding `#!/usr/bin/python` as a first line and then `chmod u+x your-script.py`. In Windows it can be done in `Right Click on file -> Open With -> Other -> [select Python.exe] -> [check Always open with selected] -> Ok` or by [doing some changes in Windows Registry](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/tech-tip-modify-the-open-with-list-in-windows-xp/5288934).